# How to throw exception or show error in suitable in ASP.NET webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I am developing a web service using ASP.NET, I am not using WCF. I am using legacy web service technology. I want clients to pass credentials in soap header for every request in order to validate them in. I created a authentication function. I do not want to call that function in every function of my service class.

So I call that function inside constructor of my service class. If validation fails, I want to throw exception. But I know this is not suitable way of throwing exception in web service. What is the most efficient way of throwing exception in .NET web service?

Below is my code:

**My service code**

```
public class math : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public AuthHeader Authentication;

    public math()
    {
        if(Authentication==null || Authentication.Username!="username" || Authentication.Password!="mypassword")
        {
            throw new Exception("Authentication failed");
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("Authentication",Required=true)]
    public int Sum(int num1,int num2)
    {
            return num1 + num2;

    }
}
```

**My authentication header class**

```
public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a _reason_ not to use WCF? ASMX should not be used for new development. Among other things, if you were using WCF, you could return a specific SOAP Fault to your clients. You can't do that easily with ASMX.

Comment: @waiyan Try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6d0x301k(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in case of any error ( Authentication Error in your case) rather throwing exceptions, returned a soap error response (WebServiceError class below).

```
public class WebServiceError
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But I am throwing inside constructor . Cause I do not want to call that function in every method .

Comment: So this one cannot be used .